# How can i change click function when clicked second time

Tags: javascript, html, css, delphi, tms

Basically i got dynamic buttons has same click event. When i click different button i have to show some different panel. i did that but user/me can't hide the panels i showed up. So i think if i can learn lets say i have number one button and number two button when they clicked they are going to show their specific panels i got it done but When i click second time on number one or number two button i want to hide that button's panels.

(only got one panel i writing in specific button's contents)

- has dynamic buttons
- All dynamic buttons has same click event
- All the buttons has to show same panel but with different content
- Want to Learn how to know which dynamic button clicked second time
- Using Delphi TMS Web

so i can hide panel

Comment: Please add your current Code so we can help you further.

Comment: Where is the relevant code of this problem? and your attempt to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using a javascript function for that
If you want multiple buttons to do the same it's the best option to do that

My solution:

```js
function changeobj(objid) {
  let displaytypes = {
    "none": "inline",
    "inline": "none"
  };
  let obj = document.getElementById(objid);
  if (obj) {
    obj.style.display = displaytypes[obj.style.display] || "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<body style="background-color: darkcyan;">
  <button onclick="changeobj('test')">toggleview</button>
  <br>
  <h id="test">test</h>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just look for the appearance (display) state of the element (card) and toggle the flow of the function with the **`if`** condition check like this:

```js
    const element = {style: {display: 'none'}}
    
    function toggleCard(element){
      if(element.style.display === 'none'){
        element.style.display = 'block'
        //more code
      }
      else{
        element.style.display = 'none'
        //more code
      }
    }
    
    toggleCard(element)
    
    console.log(element.style.display)
```